# Ring theory question.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Why is a field with 27 elements has characteristic 3?

I was solving a question and I came to know this fact which I didn't know before.
Is there anyone who can explain this to me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is well explained in [Finite Field on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)

All finite fields of some fixed size are unique (up to isomorphism), and any field of size $p^k$ has characteristic $p$.

Comment: must that p be prime?

Comment: @user114873 yes of course, if you want a field. Otherwise, you only get rings, with divisors of zero.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic has to be a prime. Since the additive group has $27$ elements, it must divide $27$.

Comment: Is there any theorem for this?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @user114873 Note that a field has no (non-zero) zero-divisors so that if $ab=0$ it follows that $a=0$ or $b=0$. If we call $1+1+\dots +1, r$ where there are $n$ $1$s added together, and if the order of $1$ is $n=pq$ as integers then we have $pq=0$ in the field. So $p=0$ or $q=0$ (which means a number of copies of $1$ add to give zero).

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic of $F$ is the order of $1$ in the additive group of $F$, which is a divisor of $|F|$ per group theory and is a prime (or zero) for any field.